# Get the SUM of a DATEDIFF result

Tags: sql-server, sum, datediff

I have a SQL statement (MS SQL Server 2012) that makes a simple calculation of the differences in dates in some records. I want to return the total / sum of the DATEDIFFs as well.

This is my query:

```
with cte as (
    select ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Date) as ID, Die_ID, Date, Status
    from Tooling_Status
    where (date between '2018-02-27 00:00:00' and '2019-02-27 11:59:59')
    and Date is not null)
select DATEDIFF (ss, c1.Date, min (c2.Date)) as Seconds, convert (nvarchar (10), c1.Date, 120) as DIA
from cte c1
left outer join cte c2
on c1.Date < c2.Date and c1.Die_ID = c2.Die_ID
where c1.Status = 2 and c2.Status = 1
group by c1.Date
order by DIA desc
```

And this my result:

```
Seconds DAY
2253    2019-02-27
166     2019-02-27
17      2019-02-27
104     2019-02-27
36      2019-02-27
11      2019-02-07
20      2019-02-07
32      2019-02-07
22      2019-02-07
27      2019-02-07
33      2019-02-07
15      2019-02-07
34      2019-02-07
120     2019-02-04
99420   2019-01-07
60      2018-09-26
```

I need this result:

```
Seconds   DAY
2732      2019-02-27
194       2019-02-07
120       2019-02-04
99420     2019-01-07
60        2018-09-26
```

Thanks For Help!

Comment: you posted html -- this is not a website which allows that.  you question should be in text

Comment: While markdown accepts some basic HTML tags better to avoid using them because reformatting of your code snippets in more readable content is not easy task now

Comment: Please check the formatting options before you post. No need to put all that HTML markup in there. This will only mess up syntax highlighting. I've fixed this post, but you should do that yourself next time; well written and well formatted questions are more likely to get anwsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few adjustments

- Extra GROUP BY using a derived table
- Removed unnecessary casts to a string
- Formatting...

SQL:

```
WITH cte
AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS ID,
           Die_ID,
           Date,
           Status
    FROM Tooling_Status
    WHERE (date      BETWEEN '2018-02-27 00:00:00' AND '2019-02-27 11:59:59'      )
          AND Date IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT SUM(d.Seconds) AS Seconds 
, d.DIA AS [Day]
FROM (
     SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, c1.Date, MIN(c2.Date)) AS Seconds,
           CAST(c1.Date AS DATE) AS DIA
     FROM cte c1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cte c2
            ON c1.Date < c2.Date
               AND c1.Die_ID = c2.Die_ID
     WHERE c1.Status = 2 AND c2.Status = 1
     GROUP BY c1.Date
) d
GROUP BY d.DIA
ORDER BY [Day] DESC;
```

Comment: I copied the query and it gave me an error:
Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Can not perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Yeps, I noticed that you already had some aggregations for datediff calculation. The query adjusted using derived table and outer aggregation.